# JQuery iterating through a loop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have tried several ways to loop through a set of 4 li elements, each with a class of "item_n" where in is an integer 1-4. I need to increment by 1 with each click. I have come close, but it ended up getting worse. Here is my semi-working code:

```
$('input.compare').change(function(){
    var me = $(this).attr("refid");
    $('li.item_1').append('<img src="images/submenu/' + me + '.png" alt="compare1" height="28" width="28" />');
});
```

I need to loop through the li.item_1 selector like $('li.item_"+i"') with each click until four is reached.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try:

```
$('input.compare').change(function(){
    var me = $(this).attr("refid");
    $('li [class^=item_]').each(function(){
         var me = $(this).name();
         $(this).append('<img src="images/submenu/' + me + '.png" alt="compare1" height="28" width="28" />');
        });
});
```

where `[class^=item_]` will get any class that li has and start with `item_`

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't explain well enough. I have 4 li elements, like the following: 
    <ul>
      <li class="item_1"></li>
      <li class="item_2"></li>
      <li class="item_3"></li>
      <li class="item_4"></li>
    </ul>

When the user clicks any one of the input.compare elements, I need to append the first li[class='item_1'] with an image.
When the user clicks any one of the remaining input.compare elements, it appends li[class='item_2'], and so on until the final li[class='item_4'] is appended. After the last one is appended I need to display an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will allow you to enumerate if you give them all the same class.

```
$('input.compare').change(function(){
   $(".itemclass").each(function(){
     // do what you need
     alert($(this).name())
   });
 });
```